# Using expect matcher in Rspec

Tags: rspec

I'm pretty sure this is an incredibly dumb question, but I'm new to Cucumber, Ruby and Rspec and I'm struggling with something extremely basic.

I installed the rspec gem and I would like to use the expectations matchers:
expect(actual).to eq(expected)

It seems like I should be able to simply require rspec/expectations and then execute these commands, however it does not work.

What am I missing?

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > require 'rspec'
 => true 
1.9.3-p448 :002 > require 'rspec/expectations'
 => true 
1.9.3-p448 :003 > expected = "this"
 => "this" 
1.9.3-p448 :004 > actual = "this"
 => "this" 
1.9.3-p448 :005 > expect(actual).to eq(expected)
NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for main:Object
from (irb):5
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Strangely 'should' works fine.

```
1.9.3-p448 :006 > expected.should == actual
 => true
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Cucumber, you can simply include the 'rspec/expectations' in your env.rb file and then use the expected syntax in your step definitions.

env.rb:

```
 require 'rspec/expectations'
```

steps.rb:

```
 Then(/^I should be able to use rspec$/) do
   expected = "this"
   actual= "this"
   expect(actual).to eql(expected)
 end
```

My mistake was mistakingly testing this syntax in the ruby console. You cannot do that since Cucumber does some automagic stuff for you.

"When cucumber sees the Spec::Matchers and Spec::Expectations modules defined, it will implicitly include them in the World in which the steps are executed."

Answer (score 2):

I would really love to be able to experiment with expect() matchers in the Rails console. I realize I can wrap them in a describe/it block, but I don't get a useful result in the console.

`describe "basic rspec feasure" do it "should do my bidding" do expect(:a).to eq(:a) end; end`
which returns `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2`

Does anyone have insight into how one might be able to do such a thing? I'm curious what the path of sending pass/failure conditions is within the rspec internals. I realize this is an atypical and advanced usage of rspec, but I'm curious ;)

Comment: `test = describe "basic rspec feasure" do it "should do my bidding" do expect(:a).to eq(:a) end; end`  `test.run` will be true if the test pass